# why there is PointerException while running code

Tags: java, exception, error-handling

i am getting java.lang.NullPointerException for below code. Don't know where is the mistake.
please look at the below code. I am trying to split video into specified size.

```
import java.io.*;

class Split
{


public static void main(String args[])throws IOException
 {

Console con=System.console();
System.out.println("enter the file path");
String path=con.readLine();
File f= new File(path);
int filesize=(int)f.length();
  try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(path)) {
      int size;
      System.out.println("enter file size for split");
      size=Integer.parseInt(con.readLine());
      byte b[]=new byte[size];
      int ch,c=0;
      while(filesize>0)
      {
          ch=fis.read(b,0,size);


          filesize = filesize-ch;


          String fname=c+"."+f.getName()+"";
          c++;
          FileOutputStream fos= new FileOutputStream(new File(fname));
          fos.write(b,0,ch);
          fos.flush();
          fos.close();

      }
    }

}

}
```

Comment: Please cut and paste full output error.

Comment: How are you running this code? Is it from console of from IDE like Eclipse?

Comment: run:
enter the file path
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at Split.main(Split.java:12)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)